# Getting rid of the inefficiency of redundant dereference

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, dereference

### Problem

I have an object with unique_ptr as a field:

```
class SomeObject
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> someUnique;
public:
    // ...
};
```

When I want to pass the object to a function without passing its ownership, I have to pass it by reference. Thus I have two dereferences instead of one. Since I have some virtual functions, it can't always be optimized away. How can I get rid of this inefficiency?

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y84dj9Yfb).

### Solution

I don't like this solution, although it's working.

I can seperate the ownership from the classes - from all (except some dedicated structs, for ownership only, and without any methods or private fields) of the classes. Thus, no class will ever contain things like unique_ptr, but only raw pointers. Because sometimes (most of the times, actually) it makes sense to couple the lifetime of an object to some resource, I will have the next struct:

```
template<typename THeld, typename THolder>
struct Unit
{
    THeld held;
    THolder holder;
};
```

When holder a is unique_ptr or tuple of unique_ptrs or something, and held is an object that can be copied freely and has only raw pointers, if any.

But this solution is really code bloating, because now each (or at least, a lot of) class should have static Make(...) function, which returns a Unit and allocates the appropriate resources. (Unfortonately, it took me time to understand that it such a code bloat)

Is there a better solution?

P.S. Yes, performace are really crucial.

Comment: Your Compiler Explorer example shows the one instruction cost of dereferencing a reference, but it doesn't show the cost of passing an object by value, which can be much more.

Comment: The difference between 2 examples is passing by value vs by reference, not because of `unique_ptr<>`. If you pass both by reference, then you get double dereference in both cases.

Comment: Sure, But I can't pass the unique_ptr by value without passing ownership @Eugene

Comment: It _can_ be, but in the case of a single member (the pointer), it isn't @DrewDormann

Comment: But passing by value is more expensive than an additional deference for any real object owned by `unique_ptr<>`. I hope you don't use `unique_ptr<int>` in  real code like you do in the example.

Comment: Sometimes it needed to use unique_ptr<int> in order to share some value between parts of the project and being able to update it. Anyway, the int (or whatever) won't get copy either case - it passed by pointer

Comment: If you need a non-owning pointer, just pass an `int*` rather than a reference to a `unique_ptr<int>`.  If you want something more self-documenting, use `std::experimental::observer_ptr<int>` or write your own `observer_ptr` if that's not available in your toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

Add a member function `.get()` to `SomeObject` which returns a `SomeNotOwnedObject` which holds a pointer obtained from `someUnique.get()` and pass that by-value to functions.

This basically wraps the usual convention of passing non-owning pointers as raw pointers, and `std::unique_ptr::get()` in case of pointers owned by a `std::unique_ptr`.

`SomeNotOwnedObject` is then a "fancy pointer" extending the behavior of a native pointer and `SomeObject` is the `std::unique_ptr` equivalent supporting the "fancy" interface of `SomeNotOwnedObject`.